# Java DatePicker popup calendar

Tags: java, jdatechooser, jcalendar

I have downloaded Microba DatePicker and JDatePicker. Can I make it always stay popped up from the start (without actioning the button, and even after choosing the date to remain popped up). What I actually want is getting just the calendar itself, without the other elements.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked Microba components.

You have mentioned

> What I actually want is getting just the calendar itself, without the other elements.

in your question.

So you can use calenderPane instead of using DatePicker on microba components.

You can use this calendar because it always remain popped!

[image]

Just use the method `getDate()` to retrieve the selected date to your textbox or whatever you want!

Here is the link to [microba calanderpane doucumentation](http://libmicroba-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1:0.4.4.3-2/classcom_1_1michaelbaranov_1_1microba_1_1calendar_1_1CalendarPane.html/%22Documentaion%20link%22)

See it works

[image]

Simply use this code to get text to your text box.

```
    Date date = calendarj.getDate();        
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    String format = df.format(date);
    txtDate.setText(format);
```

I hope it will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using jdatepicker library you could also create a JDatePanel widget which is always visible.

On the screenshot, on the left hand is the widget embedded as a JDatePanel, on the right hand you see the widget as a JDatePicker which is collapsed.

[image: JDatePicker screenshot]